# Remove specific td border?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why this is rendering correctly with or without the `.container` in css `color: red;`. What's going on behind the code and how will I achieve the second image without removing the `.container`?

```css
.container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.container table td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.no-border-right {
  border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="no-border-right">One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image: Current Output]
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Bump! Your description is very confusing. Are you trying to find where your CSS is being overwritten or what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The image is not displaying, it should help with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: After the update it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do

```
.container table td.no-border-right {
        border-right: solid 1px #FFF;
        color: red;
 }
```

.container table td has more specificity than .no-border-right

It's better not to use !important unless absolutely necessary as. First work within the rules of specificity as best as you can

Checkout [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) and this [calculator of specificity](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.no-border-right {
    border-right: solid 1px #FFF !important;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `border-right: solid 1px #FFF!important;`

```css
.container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.container table td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.no-border-right {
  border-right: solid 1px #FFF!important;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="no-border-right">One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS gives a higher priority to selectors with parents, therefore nullifying the order in the document.

Simple fix: replace your "`.no-border-right`" selector with "`.container table td.no-border-right`".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/9cst9598/1/).

The key css property is `border-collapse:collapse;`. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse).

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black;
}
td {
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

.no-border-right{
    border-right:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Growing an ugly duckling into a swan

### Step 1 - Increasing [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Placing `.container` before `.no-border-right` will increase its [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), ***but*** looks ugly! Look at these ugly gaps:

[image: Ugly!]

### Step 2 - Beautify your table

#### Let's go one step further and make this:

[image: Not Ugly!]

In order to remove those gaps, let's:

- Use the default `border-collapse: separate`
- Use `border-spacing: 0` to remove the default gaps between cells
- Place the top and left border on the table itself
- Place the right and bottom border on the cells
- Remove the right border on `.no-border-right` *and* the left border on the cell next to it (targeted with [the adjacent selector `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors))

### Working Example

```css
.container table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
  border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
.container table td {
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
.container .no-border-right {
  border-right: none;
  color: red;
}
.container .no-border-right + td {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="no-border-right">One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```